# Implementing gift card

Tags: asp.net, sql, paypal

I'm meeting an issue to implement gift card in an e-commerce website working with paypal.
I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Once the user has validate his cart, he can enter a code as gift card to get a discount. The gift card (and the code) can be used only once and it isnt linked to the user.

So when the user enter the code, I check if it exist if it allready has been used, get the discount and so on...

On the postsale of paypal (once the paiment has been accepted), I set the gift card as used.

Now, how can I prevent the gift card beeing used twice (or more). Because when user enter the code and goes to paypal, another user can use this same gift card while the first user did'nt confirm the paiment (and didnt process the postsale).

I thought giving a status to the gift card, for instance 'In use' before redirecting to paypal but if the user leave paypal without confirming his purchase, the gift card will always be InUse and then I wouldnt be able to check it again....

I hope I've been understood and thanx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could check if the code has been used when they enter it, then check again at the point of the transaction being completed.  The second check would have to be implemented carefully, with a single locking database transaction that checks if the code has been used, then marks it as being used.

If the code had been used by someone else before the transaction is completed, the transaction would have to fail with an error.  However, presumably this would be quite a rare case.

Beyond this, I wonder if you should rethink your design.  A single-use code that is not linked to a user seems unusual--normally this *would* be linked to a specific user, which would make it easier to handle.  What is your use case?

Comment: Well the code is use as gift card. Any one can buy a gift card, he recieve a code and the code can be used by any user... So I can't check who use it

Comment: Could you set the gift card to be "in use" along with the user IP address. When the user completes the check in, mark it as "used". If the user does not complete the checkout leave the gift card status as "in use" for a set period of time, say 5 minutes. After that any IP address can again use the gift card.

Comment: @blop, in most purely electronic gift card systems, the card is sent *to* the recipient's email address and can only be used by an account associated with that email address.  I would be worried about the security of gift cards that can be used by anyone.

Comment: @dan1111 I will consider that and see how I can link it to an email.

Comment: Looking at iTunes gift cards which you can buy in an supermarket in the UK: "to redeem iTunes Gift Cards:

The gift card recipient must ...
Open iTunes and click iTunes Store.
Click Redeem in the Quick Links tab.
Enter the code printed on your Gift Card when requested
Start downloading and enjoy

so maybe you need to have a step first where you link the gift card with a user account, so you know who's using it.